# Problem in using libraries in and out of virtual environments on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have installed `opencv4` on my `raspberry pi` on a virtual environment, but my python script has other modules like `picamera` and `tensorflow` which is not recognized inside a virtual environment and I cannot use `OpenCV` outside of the virtual environment.

I need help to figure this out.

Comment: can I add pythonpath for OpenCV library or can I install OpenCV outside virtual environment again. If its the second case, how do I remove all the dependencies installed for OpenCV and reinstall it.

Comment: If you forgot to mention about something in your question, you can always edit it and update your post.

Comment: okay I'll do that from now on